# What is the least memory usage for a binary file on UNIX-like OS?

Tags: c, unix, posix, system-calls

I'm actually attending an operating system course at university.
The professor has told us about fread(), fwrite() ... C functions and read(), write() ... system calls.
My doubt became when I had to define the block's size and the number of blocks. As the documentation says this functions return the exact number of blocks red or written.
So my question is: is it possible to have a file on the hard disk smaller than one byte, or is possible to have a file which dimension is not a multiple of Byte?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: as someone suggested I've not posted a practical example. This is the exercise I'm working on. It's just a program that clones a file
https://gitlab.com/clementefnc/laboratori_so/blob/master/Lab01/Es4/Es4p4.c

Comment: no and no.......

Comment: Neither one are possible.

Comment: Typically, files are allocated in units of disk blocks, which will usually be a power of two that's usually at least 512 (occasionally, for old floppy disks, as small as 128) bytes; on a modern hard disk, it'll often be a block size of 4096 or a bigger power of two. You cannot store less than one byte in a file; on disk, even a one byte file will occupy much more space than just a single byte.  The details depend on the file system type for the disk drive.

Comment: BTW: there are also files with *holes* in them. (but  they still cost an inode and maybe indirect blocks)

Comment: 0 byte files are quite common. It is not possible to have a file that is more thna 0 bytes and less than 1 byte

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about a *specific, practical problem* encountered in the course of software development. (A practical question -- f/e, how to efficiently store individual binary flags in bulk on limited storage -- might be better received; but it's hard to see a practical use for the answer to a question looking only at file size as such and ignoring metadata -- inodes, directory entries, etc).

Comment: @TerryCarmen: even if the data for a file is zero bytes long, there are no file systems where the metadata is zero bytes long too.  There's an element of cheating there — the question doesn't delve into such details.

Comment: ...to expand on that, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic -- **and**ed into the other requirements is that something be a (1) practical, (2) answerable, (3) problem, and also be (4) unique to software development. I'd argue that this fails on criteria (1) and (3): Ignoring metadata makes it impractical; and I don't see a problem (which an answer to the question would solve) stated at all.

Comment: Multics let you specify the size of a file in bits, but I think i/o was still done in round multiples of pages (1024 36-bit words).

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to have a file on the hard disk smaller than one byte, or is possible to have a file which dimension is not a multiple of Byte?

Yes, in theory this is entirely possible. "Files" are an abstraction and nothing prevents the existence of an OS that has different limitations or a completely different abstraction for "files". In fact, the minimum unit supported by hardware is typically a block of many bytes (e.g. a 512 byte sector) and the OS is already providing "smaller than minimum size supported by hardware" abstractions.

In practice, no operating system has ever supported this; and it's hard to see a use case for it (so it's unlikely that any operating system will support it in future).

Comment: in C land (OP refers to read, write, fread, fwrite) the file IO operations are defined in terms of bytes. The counts read and write are integers and the smallest unit is byte. Ie the POSIX abstraction of a file is a stream of bytes. (A byte may not be 8 bits though)

Comment: @pm100: Yes, but POSIX extends the standard C library in multiple ways, and every modern Unix-like OS extends SYS-V in multiple ways. You can (in theory) have a program written in C (using extension/s) running on a "certified Unix" operating system (not just "Unix-like") that provides the ability to read/write bits from files.

Comment: He means that no OS has ever had a smaller-than-1-byte unit for file length; i.e., you can't have an 11-bit long file. Certainly OSs/FSs can be built to have more than one file per disk block: ReiserFS on Linux did it.